# negative effect on opacity transition inside transformed element

Tags: html, css, transform, css-transitions, opacity

Please, try this in action. I change opacity on one element and this affects the look of another static element which contains text. It's hard to explain, just try and tell me how can I avoid this effect. It seems to me that this happens only when using chain of transforms.

http://jsfiddle.net/6p8jf3d3/

HTML:

`<div class="outer">
        <div class="inner"></div>
        <div class="text">Hello</div>
    </div>`

CSS:

```
div.outer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;

        -ms-transform: skew(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
            transform: skew(-45deg);
}

div.inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #99CCFF;
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
            transition: all 0.5s;
}

div.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;  
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;

        -ms-transform: skew(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(45deg);
            transform: skew(45deg);
}

div.outer:hover div.inner {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: You could at least put it in a jsfiddle. Not many volunteers want to do all your work for you. Aside that, look into `-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;`

Comment: When I put it in jsfiddle, someone comments that I should put code here in post .... oh

Comment: You should post the code here, for references to another one looking for this subject in the future, in case the link goes down. But the jsfiddle is usefull as it allows us to easily test the behavior of your code and you will get answers more quickly.

Comment: So, original problem took place in Chrome, Firefox and Opera. In Safari (for Windows) there was no negative effect. 
After adding -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; with and without vendor prefix, effect has changed differently in different browsers. Now all browsers except Firefox has negative effect, Firefox is clear. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `transform: translateZ(0);` to `div.inner` will stop the hopping/jarring effect of the transition, but it keeps the stack fuzz on it.  It's better, but not perfect:

**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6p8jf3d3/2/)**

Comment: -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    backface-visibility: hidden;

helps a lot too.

Comment: @PawlikDoc - Looks like it does the exact same thing that `transform: translateZ(0);` does.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I think it looks like we need to find some combination of this options for different browsers...

Comment: @PawlikDoc - For all browsers that accept transforms, the `translateZ(0)` option should work.  Backface-visibility isn't a cure-all for 3D translations.  It's used primarily to prevent an element that is "flipped" from flickering at the end of the transform as both sides attempt to display themselves.  Other effects in the browser are merely side-effects, and are not guaranteed to always function the way you're anticipating them to.  The reason the `translateZ` works is similar to the `backface-visibility` and shouldn't need to be doubly accounted for as you're describing.

Comment: So, I've experimented a bit (not with this jsfiddle but with larger example) and found solution for Chrome, Safari, Opera and Firefox. Combination of translateZ, backface-visibility and transform-style.
http://jsfiddle.net/6p8jf3d3/4/

Comment: @PawlikDoc - Still looks the same as the translateZ option to me, but if that's your answer you should submit it and accept it!

Answer (score 0):

So, I've experimented a bit (not with this jsfiddle but with larger example) and found solution for Chrome, Safari, Opera and Firefox. Combination of translateZ, backface-visibility and transform-style. jsfiddle.net/6p8jf3d3/4

CSS:

```
div.outer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;

        -ms-transform: skew(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
            transform: skew(-45deg);

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

div.inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #99CCFF;
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
            transition: all 0.5s;

        -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
            transform: translateZ(0);
}

div.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;  
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;

        -ms-transform: skew(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(45deg);
            transform: skew(45deg);

    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;   
}

div.outer:hover div.inner {
    opacity: 1;
}
```